# How to Split result that I get from CMD into variable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to split result from CMD in if it is match it will insert it into my RichTextBox

this is my code:

```cs
private void NetWorkCheker_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/c ipconfig /all",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    proc.Start();

    while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        Result.Text += "\r\n"+ proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    }

    proc.WaitForExit();

    string SplitValue = Result.Text; // here I want to split the result from my RichTextBox
    MessageBox.Show(SplitValue);
}
```

I am stuck here so I need someone to fix my code if it is possible.

Comment: `ipconfig` seems a litle awkward to query this information - have you considered using [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces?view=net-5.0#)?

Comment: but this will dispaly result in console only, how to use result into RichTextBox ?

Comment: The suggestion is not to start `ipconfig` as a Process and use the managed Library instead. You get the same information. Set the results to whatever Control you want.

Comment: @jimi Can you guide me I am not that much stronger in C#.

Comment: Did you try the make use of the example you found in the docs that @Filburt linked? You can use a StringBuilder and replace all `Console.WriteLine()` with `Append()` or `AppendFormat()` or `AppendLine()`, then set the Text property of a Control with `[StringBuilder].ToString()`

Comment: Yes I tried but it doesn't work with me =:| the code that I wrote it up If it is possible to split it will be fine for me because I can complete my project if there any similar like this I will be happy I was stuck on this code more that 2 days

Comment: *"... it doesn't work with me"* is not a useful problem description. Please **show** what you have tried. Also try to familiarize yourself with an object oriented programming language instead of trying to bend it to work like unix/linux console tools.

Comment: brother it dosn't work with me so I post my question as answer so you can check it.

Comment: You need to include an example of the string that you want to see in your message box, that will help, there are 2 issues here, 1 how to split and format strings, 2 if you use the API you do not need to manipulate strings at all like this!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer after long time with multiple tries

this is the code:

```
        private void linkLabel8_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    { 
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "/c ipconfig /all",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        string DHCP = "";
        proc.Start();
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine(), "Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : ")) // find results under match if match Lease Expires
            {
                DHCP += "\r\n" + proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // set value to var
            }

        }  
            proc.WaitForExit();
        Result.Text += "\r\n" + DHCP.Split(new string[] {"NetBIOS"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];// split result from CMD into richtextbox
    }
```

Comment: Whilst is is great that you found a solution, I want to discourage anyone from attempting to do this they way you have suggested, C# has standard managed APIs to access the same information, please edit your original question to include the output that you are expecting and we can show a far simpler solution

Comment: brother this is the best way that I want to do it so it will help me more and more, so any result from CMD I can split it and check what ever I want from CMD, because my work focus on CMD to much